# Symfony2 Entity Authentication doesn't work for me

Tags: authentication, symfony, entity

I am learning how to use Authentication in Symfony2, with usernames comming from an Entity (MySQL database). I've created a simple table in PhpMyAdmin :

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `salt`, `roles`) VALUES
(1, 'bobby4078', 'test', '', ''),
(2, 'damien', 'test', '', ''),
(3, 'thomas', 'test', '', '');
```

As you can see, there is juste 3 users, with the same password "test", no salt and roles.

Then I've edited my security.yml :

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Rtf\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        main:
            entity: { class: RtfUserBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            provider: main
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

To finish, here is my entity (I hope this is not too long) :

```
namespace Rtf\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Rtf\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function _construct(){
        $this->roles = array();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param array $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public  function eraseCredentials(){

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I entered a login and a password in my form, then in my symfony toolbar I can see that the user is still "anon". So It didn't read properly in my database...

I really don't know where this could comes from, and I don't know where to start searching for errors in my code...

Any help ?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can use the FOSUserBundle instead, which does all the authentication, registration an management stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've set `anonymous: true` under `firewalls.main`. I'm not a Symfony expert, but I guess that as long as you allow anonymous users in the area, you're going to count as an anonymous user even though you're logged in. Try adding this to your `access_control`:

```
  - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This should make sure that all users visiting `/` is logged in to an account with the `ROLE_USER` role. I don't know what effect this will have with `anonymous: true` in the firewall though, you'll just have to test. Try changing the `roles` field of the snippet above to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` and see what effect that has on the user.

This probably means that you won't have access with any of your accounts, since you have left "roles" blank. Try adding "ROLE_USER" to the "role" column of all your users, then change the `getRoles` function of your `User` entity to:

```
function getRoles() {
    return explode(',', $this->roles);
}
```

This means that you can now keep a comma-separated list of roles in your database.

Let me know if any of the above helped/didn't help/made your Symfony project explode.